# Systemverilog interface definition - lint error message

Tags: system-verilog, vlsi, asic

I'm using Systemverilog interfaces to enable the implementation of generic functions.
The interface is defined in one file as follows:

```
interface interface_onehot_to_binary

# (parameter WIDTH_ONEHOT=16)
(); // Empty port list

localparam WIDTH_BINARY = $clog2 (WIDTH_ONEHOT) ;
    function logic [WIDTH_BINARY-1:0] onehot_to_binary
    (logic [WIDTH_ONEHOT-1: 0] onehot);
    automatic logic [WIDTH_BINARY-1:0] binary=0;
        foreach (onehot[index])
        begin
            if (onehot[index]==1'b1) begin
                binary=binary|index;
            end
        end
        return binary;
    endfunction

endinterface
```

And then instantiated in another file as follows:

```
interface_onehot_to_binary
#(.WIDTH_ONEHOT(256))
inst_interface_onehot_to_binary
(); // Empty port list
```

The simulation and synthesis tools that I use digest this code without issues.
But the SpyGlass linter fails with the following error message:
interface 'interface_onehot_to_binary' declaration does not have a modport definition.
The error points to the first file - where the interface is defined.
What's wrong with my code? How can it be solved?

Comment: This seems like a strange use of an `interface`. Why not put your function in a `package`?

Comment: Because I want the function to be generic. To my understanding, if I store the function in a package I'll have to statically declare WIDTH_ONEHOT using a localparam in that package. An interface on the other hand allows me to pass the width using a parameter.

Comment: You can make the function a static method of a parameterized class. (and synthesizable).

Comment: I would love to learn that. Can you please post an example of my function modified to the form that you mentioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class class_onehot_to_binary

# (parameter WIDTH_ONEHOT=16);

localparam WIDTH_BINARY = $clog2 (WIDTH_ONEHOT) ;
    static function logic [WIDTH_BINARY-1:0] onehot_to_binary
    (logic [WIDTH_ONEHOT-1: 0] onehot);
    logic [WIDTH_BINARY-1:0] binary=0;
        foreach (onehot[index])
        begin
            if (onehot[index]==1'b1) begin
                binary=binary|index;
            end
        end
        return binary;
    endfunction

endclass
```

Note that even though `onehot_to_binary` has a static class qualifier, the function has an automatic lifetime.

You would call this using `class_onehot_to_binary#(32)::onehot_to_binary(value)`

Comment: Thanks! If the class is declared in a package - shouldn't we call it as some_pkg::class_onehot_to_binary#(32)::onehot_to_binary(value) ?